# JS How to return all the people with the same last name

Tags: javascript, arrays, names, arr

I'm new to coding and have been given this question, but I'm unsure to why my code doesn't work.

This is the question I have been given;

Create a function that takes an array of full names and returns an array containing only the people whose last name is Smith.

```
  E.g. ['Charlotte Jones', 'Rebecca Smith', 'Harry Smith', 'John Smithy', 'Smith Jones'] => ['Rebecca Smith', 'Harry Smith']
```

This is the code that I have written;

```js
function getSmiths(arr) {
  return arr.filter(a =>a.includes("Smith"))
 }
 
 console.log(getSmiths(['Charlotte Jones', 'Rebecca Smith', 'Harry Smith', 'John Smithy', 'Smith Jones']));
```

my code is being run against this test;

```
describe("getSmiths", () => {
  it("returns [] when passed []", () => {
    expect(getSmiths([])).to.eql([]);
  });
 it("returns a Smith from a mixed arrau", () => {
    expect(getSmiths(["Harry Smith", "Charlotte Bank"])).to.eql([
      "Harry Smith"
    ]);
  });
  it("returns multiple Smiths from a mixed array", () => {
    expect(getSmiths(["Harry Smith", "Charlotte Bank"])).to.eql([
      "Harry Smith"
    ]);
  });
  it("ignores Smiths found in first names", () => {
     expect(getSmiths(["Smithy Jones", "Harry     Smith"])).to.eql(["Harry Smith"]);
  });
  it("ignores Smiths found in extended last names", () => {
     expect(getSmiths(["John Smith", "Chris Smithy"])).to.eql(["John     Smith"]);
  });
});
```

Dose anyone have any suggestion to why my code doesn't work?

Comment: `why my code doesn't work` Because `.includes` will pass *first* names of `Smith` as well

Comment: You might like [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're using include which will search for smith in the complete string.

1. Using `endsWith`

```js
let arr = ['Charlotte Jones', 'Rebecca Smith', 'Harry Smith', 'John Smithy', 'Smith Jones'];

    let op = arr.filter(e=> e.endsWith('Smith'))

    console.log(op);
```

2. Using regex

```js
let arr = ['Charlotte Jones', 'Rebecca Smith', 'Harry Smith', 'John Smithy', 'Smith Jones'];

let op = arr.filter(e=> /\ssmith$/ig.test(e))

console.log(op);
```

Comment: Might need to be careful with the regex since last names can be complex (i.e. `"Janice O'Smith"`) a space is probably safer than `\b`

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen specifically which tests in the test group are failing?

Your method to return all array members that include the string 'Smith' will return an array of items that have 'Smith' in them ANYWHERE, and will return the exact string.

In your 4th test of the group you will get back both array items, and as they are recorded (i.e. the second item will return as "Harry      Smith".

In your last test, you will also get back both items, and the first item will be returned as "John Smith".

You need to change the test for your filter to only test against last name (hint: perhaps split each string and test against last name? - I'll let you work out how to do that).

I think that last test is always going to fail as you have written it.  I suspect it was meant to return "John Smith" and you should be ensuring that "Smithy" fails the test.  If so, you'll want to further your filter to ensure the last name EQUALS "Smith" rather than includes it.

Good luck!